# Error while creating node using py2neo : keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo, property-graph

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
l=["Vipul", "Vithal", "Yoga"]
hasage=["hasAge", "hasAge", "hasAge"]
age=[24,31,26]

g = Graph(password="Abc123")

tx = g.begin()
for item in l:
    Vithal = Node("item", name=l[l.index(item)], hasage[l.index(item)]=age[l.index(item)])
    tx.create(Vithal)
    tx.commit()
```

I'm getting an error:

> Vithal = Node("item", name=l[l.index(item)], hasage[l.index(item)]=age[l.index(item)])
>
> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

I'm trying to create a property name for the node with a value from the predefined list.

Comment: As the error message suggests, the keyword cannot be an expression. In fact, `hasage[l.index(item)]` does not make any sense. Is it a "boolean" attribute?

Comment: No it's not a "boolean" attribute.@sentence

Comment: Then, what is it?